# Combining form onsubmit parameter with jquery submit event handler

Tags: jquery, forms, event-handling, onsubmit, recaptcha-v3

I have a form that is being generated by legacy back-end code that, for a variety of reasons, I can't change. The form is straightforward HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="theForm" onsubmit="return check_theForm(); method="post">
  <!-- fields go here -->
</form>
```

On submission the `onsubmit` parameter fires to verify that all compulsory field have been filled in, using the `check_theform()` function which contains "plain vanilla" javascript (i.e. no jQuery code). In other words, basic stuff.

I'm now trying to add reCAPTCHA V3 to this form by adding the following:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      {action: 'contactForm'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#theForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
        $('#theForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm">');
        $('#theForm').unbind('submit').submit();
      });;
  });
});
```

The problem is that the form's `onsubmit` parameter fires first, which runs `check_theForm()`, and then the `$('#theForm').submit(function(event)` handler fires, which eventually runs `$('#theForm').unbind('submit').submit();` at which point `check_theForm()` runs a second time. If there are form errors, these are now being displayed twice.

How can I prevent this duplication without making changes to the form's HTML code or to `check_theForm()`, seeing as these are generated by legacy back-end code that I can't change?

Comment: Did you try:  `$("#theForm").attr("onsubmit", null)` ?  then call `check_theForm()` within your own submit handler, once, where you need it.

Comment: No, I didn't. This works. Tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have `onsubmit="x()"` you can remove the html onsubmit handler with

```
$("#id").attr("onsubmit", null);
```

allowing you full control without your own event handler.

In this case, giving:

```
$("#theForm").attr("onsubmit", null);

$('#theForm').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      {action: 'contactForm'}).then(function(token) {
        $('#theForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="token" value="' + token + '">');
        $('#theForm').prepend('<input type="hidden" name="action" value="contactForm">');
        if (check_theForm())
            $('#theForm').unbind('submit').submit();
      });;
  });
});
```